# Diferenco inter "...is", "estis ...anta" kaj "estas ...inta"?

Tags: grammar

Ĉu la signifoj de "ŝi instruis", "ŝi estis instruanta", "ŝi estas instruinta" samas? Se ne, kio estas la diferenco?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En ĉiuj, la ago okazas en la pasinteco, sed la signifoj estas malsamaj:

- “Ŝi instruis”: la ago okazis antaŭ nun, sed oni ne scias ĉu la ago jam finiĝis. [(PMEG: Pasinta tempo: IS-finaĵo)](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/reala/pasinta_tempo.html)
- “Ŝi estis instruanta”: la ago daŭris en la momento pri kiu oni parolas, kiu estas en la pasinteco. [(PMEG: Kunmetitaj verboformoj aktivaj: Kunmetitaj ANT-formoj)](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/kunmetitaj_verboformoj/aktivaj.html#i-dt1)
- “Ŝi estas instruinta”: la ago okazis antaŭ nun kaj (ĵus) finiĝis. [(PMEG: Kunmetitaj verboformoj aktivaj: Kunmetitaj INT-formoj)](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/kunmetitaj_verboformoj/aktivaj.html#i-68h)

Comment: From my understanding, the participles should be avoided when possible, although I'm not entirely sure why. Should the simple "sxi instruis" be modified to indicate a time period as a way of avoiding a participle construction?  Maybe "sxi instruis hieraux" or "sxi cxi-matene instruis" or "sxi lastatempe instruis"?

Comment: @ChrisMcDowell I asked a [related question](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/are-the-compound-verb-tenses-ever-really-used-in-esperanto) a while ago. Some good discussion of the advantages and disadvantages can be found in the answers there. Basically it creates a nuance that you might need in certain situations at a small expense of complexity. It would likely be recommended to avoid them as part of keeping a simple language when speaking to beginners, and they are usually significantly outnumbered in usage by simple tenses, but they sure have their place in Esperanto.

Comment: Perhaps the advice may be aimed to native English speakers to not translate every single occurrence of past perfect ("I have done") to a compound tense just because simple past would not work in the original. But Eo is always going to be influenced by how we think in our native tongues anyway, at least somewhat, and it's not a mistake.