# Are the compound verb tenses ever really used in Esperanto?

Tags: verbs

I found [this link](http://esperanto.davidgsimpson.com/eo-verbforms.html) which lists 12 compound tenses like future perfect, along with some other outlandish forms like perfect imperative (brr), further to the normal *as–is–os*. Are they used in anything than perhaps literal translations of texts from other languages? It feels like they are defeating the simplicity principle which makes Esperanto so elegant. To my best knowledge (and background from my own language), it's possible to express **any** other tense than present or future or past by words like *ĵus*, I have yet to see a counterexample.

Comment: The compound imperatives, and the future-future (for example) are quite rare, but the system is entirely regular. Can you say a bit more about which ones are confusing?

Comment: @AndrewWoods Sorry for the bad phrasing: I did not find them confusing, just superfluous.

Comment: @AndrewWoods What I meant to imply about the perfect imperative is that it would feel strange to be ordered to *have done* something – quite restricting, at least. Maybe a very uncompromising way of putting a deadline, if accompanied by a time in the same sentence, that's all use cases I can imagine. But I don't know if that would actually work in Esperanto.

Comment: Interesting thinking, I agree about the orders. But the -u form can be used in more ways than the English imperative. For example to express *should/ought to* or *Let's*. Maybe then those tenses make a little more sense.

Comment: The rejection of compound tenses in favour of simple tenses and adverbs is one of the main contributions Kabe (Kazimierz Bein) made to the language; it does not really originate with Zamenhof. As a stylistic preference, it has stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though it may seem like the compound tenses only add difficulty to the language, they do have many advantages. They are useful in literature, like you mention, but not only translated works, also originals. Below I listed some quotes from a magazine. I'd say that compound tenses are less common in spoken Esperanto, but far from non-existing.

One can use the compound tenses to express complex situations and also add variety to the writing. It might be possible to rewrite such sentences using the simple verb forms and other words like *ĵus*, but I think it is simpler to use the compound tenses.

The passive participle is often used in a way that leaves out a subject otherwise necessary. This is very common also in when speaking.

- La pordo estas ŝlosita.
- Post 30 jaroj televidiloj ne plu estos uzataj.
- Ŝi estis tre konata en Brazilio.

In the last issue of the online magazine *Umujo* compound tenses appear 13 times.

Active:

- Perfect: 1
- Progressive present: 1

Passive:

- Perfect: 5
- Progressive present: 4
- Future perfect: 1
- Perfect infinitive: 1

I picked out some examples:

> *Ni volas helpi ĉiujn lingvojn, sendepende ĉu ili **estas** gigantaj,
>   minoritataj aŭ **kreitaj**.*
>
> *Italoj **estas** multe **konataj** eksterlande por esti tre gestemaj.*
>
> *Li **estas** preskaŭ **mortinta**, kaj ne diros ion plu.*
>
> *Ni seniluziigos nian ĉefaron kaj **estos** **maldungitaj**.*
>
> *Ĝis nun mi **estas laboranta**, konsiderante ĉiujn filmetojn parto de
>   sama rakonto.*

Comment: Thanks for going through the magazine to collect real examples for me, wow! But I would say that participles alone just work like adjectives with a plain present/future/past, don't they? To me *la pordo estas ŝlosita* sounds no different from *la pordo estas ferma*, certainly not a tense of its own. It's particularly striking in the first example quoted from the magazine that we're staying within one tense. In English one could hardly imagine saying for example "I am tired and washing my hands", despite that superficially the second part has the same grammatical structure as the first.

Comment: Or maybe I'm missing what a tense is, in the first place. I usually only think of the active forms as passive is so close to adjectives.

Comment: @LaVo Ah, I get it. You were going for the active ones only. Luckily I posted the two I found. Well, I agree that the passive participles are used as adjectives. That might explain why they are so common in speach. But if you think of it that way... the active ones are adjectives too, aren't they?

Comment: Besides, I thought you wanted information about the *tenses* and not the participles themselves. The frequency of participles is much higher than the frequency of compound tenses.

Comment: I'd like to add some examples showing what I mean by variety and complex situations, but I haven't come up with/found any yet

Comment: Yes, I think it's actually a brilliant insight your answer gave me. That I was biased by considering active and passive tenses separately while systematically they should be completely analogous in a language like Esperanto. So when the passive participles feel like an adjective to me I should always be able to adapt a mindset in which I perceive the active ones just the same (which I find quite easy, now), and vice versa: if the active participles feel like independent temporal specifications, the same should be acceptable for passive ones.

Comment: I think my fault was either to associate the term "tense" only with the latter situation or to overestimate the adjective parallel. Please don't worry about putting more effort into finding further examples, I think you gave me a plenty head start for my own investigation and finding real world cases from here. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I really like the *preskaŭ mortinta*. It shows an actual temporal sequence in passive voice (*nun < hipoteze: morto < mortinta*), something I don't think I've seen anywhere else (and did not think was possible). It's not quite like saying *preskaŭ morta* as that's more like saying his state is similar to being dead. So it shows my question is just as relevant for passive, and the answer is positive.

Comment: Notice that ReVo recommends to avoid “morta” meaning “dead”, its main meaning is supposed to be “mortal, fatal, deadly”. http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/mort.html#mort.0a.zamenhofe That would explain the choice of mortinta in the citation.

Answer (score 9):

You will find people who stand by the "complex tenses." (It's likely that a few will answer here.) The point of Esperanto is to be simple, and it's possible (and encouraged) to express any thought with the basic *-as, -is,* and *-os*. If the timing of the event needs to be clarified, it can be clarified by additional words.

Participles are best thought of as adjectives. Adjectives can be combined with *estas* like this.

- *Jen verda arbo.*
- *La arbo estas verda.*

Participles can be treated the same way.

- *Jen falinta arbo.*
- *La arbo estas falinta.*

It's very tempting to see this last sentence as "the tree **has fallen**", but I like to encourage people to see it as "the tree **is** a fallen one" (it is a tree in the state of being fallen.)

So, yes, the "complex tenses" are used, but it's worth considering whether the people are using them are really embracing how Esperanto works or just carrying over bias from their national language.

Answer (score 3):

The compound tenses follow directly from allowing participles to bear tenses. The names that are shown on that website are borrowed from the grammars of other languages (and some of them are not just dubiously chosen, but misspelt).

You are not obliged to use compounds, but they aren't any more conceptually complicated than relative time itself. Without them, one would just have to express the same ideas in a haphazard way with adverbs and particles. In other words, a regular system would be replaced with an irregular system, without any gain other than a very superficial simplification in appearances.

---

(Concerning the compounds with *-u*)

The names given are misleading; the *-u* ending is not just used for the imperative; it is a "general deontic mood" expressing wishes and ideals. So, it is possible to construct examples in which it makes sense:

- *Estu travivinta tian malagrablaĵon por la lasta fojo!* May you have experienced such unpleasantness for the last time!
- *Ne estu malvenkinta...* [muttered, opening the sports section of the newspaper] Don't have lost...