# Kio estas la diferenco inter -int kaj -it?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Mi ne komprenas la diferencon inter -int kaj -it, precize instalinta kaj instalita. Mi nun tradukas aplikaĵon en Esperanton sed la traduko de "Installed" estas malfacila por mi kompreni.

Comment: Ŝajnas al mi, ke estus bone, se vi tralegos iun kurson. Mi rekommendas la kurson ["La teorio Nakamura"](https://lernu.net/eo/kurso/nakamura) de la retejo Lernu!. La kursotekstoj estas en Esperanto, sed la gramatikajn klarigojn vi povas ekhavi en multaj lingvoj, ekzemple en la angla. Vi devas registrigi vin al la retejo por havi pli ol la unuan lecionon.

Comment: Bonvolu akcepti respondon. Pro tio ke la ligilo en via propra respondo ne taŭgas (retejaj reguloj: nur komento), eble akceptu alian respondon. Tiel la demando ne plu vagas nerespondite.

Comment: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/115/diferenco-inter-is-estis-anta-kaj-estas-inta?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Imagu la jenan frazon:

> La leono manĝis cervon

Estas du bestoj en la ago. La unua faris la agon (la leono) kaj la alia estis submetita al la ago (la cervo). Kiam oni uzas *-ita* aŭ *-inta* por indiki agon, la elekto inter la du dependas de la rolo kiun la afero havas en la ago.

Se oni indikas la faranton de la ago (la leono), oni uzas *-int*. Ekzemple:

> la manĝinta leono.

Se oni indikas la submetiton de la ago (la cervo), oni uzas *-it*. Ekzemple:

> la manĝita cervo.

Aŭ:

> Manĝinta leono estas feliĉa. Manĝita cervo estas malfeliĉa.

En via ekzemplo vi plej verŝajne volas *instalita*. La aplikaĵo estas tio kion oni submetas al la ago *instali*, do ĝi estas *instalita aplikaĵo*.